# Omxplayer-wrapper will not open

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, dbus, omxplayer

I am having trouble opening the omxplayer-wrapper on my Raspberry Pi 3B, and I dont know why. I am hoping someone with a little better Linux knowledge will be able to help me out. I have followed all the steps as described in the documentation, but it still will not open.

I have a brand new install of the operating system. Bullseye Version 11. Also I have installed and upgraded, so everything is up to date.

https://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

The first line in that document says the following:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y libdbus-1{,-dev}`
When I do, the packages succsessfully install except for the following message:

`E: Unable to locate package libdbus-1`

So I install the following instead, based on some forum information:

`sudo apt install libdbus-glib-1-dev dbus libdbus-1-dev`

Okay, then I install the following:

`pip3 install omxplayer-wrapper`

The documentation says pip, but I believe pip3 should work as well. My Thonny is in 3.9.2. Both seem to install successfully, but when I run the following code from Thonny (script located in /home/pi):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from omxplayer.player import OMXPlayer
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep

VIDEO_PATH = Path("../home/pi/Videos/Detroit Day.mp4")

player = OMXPlayer(VIDEO_PATH)

sleep(5)

player.quit()
```

I get the following errors from the terminal

```
/usr/bin/omxplayer.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libbrcmEGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test2.py", line 9, in <module>
    player = OMXPlayer(VIDEO_PATH)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/omxplayer/player.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.load(source, pause=pause)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/omxplayer/player.py", line 251, in load
    self._load_source(source)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/omxplayer/player.py", line 163, in _load_source
    self._connection = self._setup_dbus_connection(self._Connection, self._bus_address_finder)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/omxplayer/player.py", line 236, in _setup_dbus_connection
    raise SystemError('DBus cannot connect to the OMXPlayer process')
SystemError: DBus cannot connect to the OMXPlayer process
```

Any ideas on a way to connect the DBus with the OMXPlayer process? This seems to be a very simple install, so I'm confused whats happening. I have seen similar problems on other forums, and they range from folder permission issues, to genuine bugs, to incorrect dependencies, python vs python3 issues...

I will be happy to post logs, and any other information

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> omxplayer is being deprecated and resources are directed at improving vlc

according to https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer.

On Bullseye that shared library files has moved to a different location according to https://dietpi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?t=9421

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Glad to know it wasn't something on my end. I will take a look at that forum, but sounds like its not such a clean install anymore.